# Why does the word Signature appear in Forum responses?

Tags: forum

I am setting up a Forum for a client (running EE 2.5.5) and have Signatures enabled, however, whenever anyone posts a reply the signature shows up like this:

> **Signature**
>
> Mark Twain
>
> CIO

I checked the template code and it shows like this:

```
<div class="fm-signature-wrapper">
<h4>{lang:signature}</h4>
{if signature_image}
    <img src="{path:signature_image}" class="fm-signature-image" border="0" width="{signature_image_width}" height="{signature_image_height}" alt="{lang:signature_image}" />
{/if}
<div class="fm-signature">
    {signature}
</div>

</div>
```

If I can just get rid of the word **Signature** I will be content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `<h4>{lang:signature}</h4>` is the culprit. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: Hi Dom, I agree, I ended up hiding it in the CSS. Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: You can delete it from the template too.